# How do I get VBA to continue through If Statement if the first condition is no longer required?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am using AfterUpdate event to update a Textbox whose condition depends on multiple conditions. The first part of my code works fine but the second part does not do anything. I assume its because VBA Exits Sub soon as the first parts condition is met. Is there a way to work around it? I am still new to VBA and I am struggling with this. Any suggestions is highly appreciated

```
Private Sub QuantityUsed_AfterUpdate()
If IsNull(QuantityUsed) Then
QuantityUsed = 0
Else: QuantityUsed = QuantityUsed.Value
End If

 'First part__________________

If Used1.Value > Total1.Value Then
Exit Sub
End If
If Used1.Value = 0 Then
Exit Sub
End If
QuantityUsed = QuantityUsed.Value + Used1

'Second part__________________

If Used2.Value > Total2.Value Then
Exit Sub
End If

If Used2.Value = 0 Then
Exit Sub
End If
QuantityUsed = QuantityUsed.Value + Used2

End Sub
```

Comment: Just to clarify, you want the second part of the Sub to run even if the first part reaches an "Exit Sub"?

Comment: [How to debug VBA code](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DebuggingVBA.aspx)

Comment: @JustinCoplin, The Second part is independent of the First part but they both exit in the     QuantityUsed_AfterUpdate     event. calling the 
    QuantityUsed_AfterUpdate     even will only exucute the first part. It would be good to continue to the second part if     Exit Sub     is reached.

Comment: Simply take the exit subs out if you want to process used 1 and used 2, or rewrite your If to handle both variables . . . .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about changing the `IF` statement a bit?

```
'...

If Not Used1.Value > Total1.Value And Used1.Value <> 0 Then 
    QuantityUsed = QuantityUsed.Value + Used1
End If

'...
```

Comment: Clearing the statements fixed the problem. Many thanks @Kostas K